# Ionic Angular : Create a fake page navigation history artificially

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there any way in Ionic 4/Angular 8 to create an array of urls in history when navigating to a route/page

The reason is that I want to create the back history when navigating to a sub page when the user clicks on a push notification, so I want the homepage to be first then the messages overview page and then finally the single message view, to put it in pseudo code Im looking to achieve this

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward(["page/home","page/messages","page/messages/123"]);
```

I then need the back button to navigate back through these pages and preferable without loading them or their assets yet

Update: It seems this was available in the older versions of ionic framework but it has been removed, would love to know why or if theres a replacement

```
        this.nav.setPages([
            {page: ChatsPage},
            {page: ChatMessagesPage, params: {id: chatId}}
        ]).catch(this.log.error)
```

Essentially id like to navigate to 2 pages